# Java Annotation at runtime

Tags: java, dynamic, annotations, runtime

the following class exists which consist from predefined UUID's  that describe possible entires of the database.

```
public class Predefined {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 25)
    public UUID phone = UUID.fromString("47b58767-c0ad-43fe-8e87-c7dae489a4f0");

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    public UUID company = UUID.fromString("f9a1e8f4-b8c0-41f2-a626-49c11da8d5c2");
}
```

Those values are received as a key pair value trough web service: and then they are put to a hashmap.

47b58767-c0ad-43fe-8e87-c7dae489a4f0 =  +00112233445566778899

f9a1e8f4-b8c0-41f2-a626-49c11da8d5c2 =  someVirtualCompnayName

When i receive an UUID that i know i am creating an instance of the Predefined class and then getting the annotations of the filed in the Predefined class i.e.:

```
Annotation[] annon = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
```

Now I need to check those annotation agains the values that I got from the web services i.e. “+00112233445566778899” and “someVirtualCompnayName” at runtime

Is this possible?
I am especially interesting in example covering JSR 303.

Shortly why I have such construct:
The  DAO , @Repository  classes have different structure i.e.

contact

contact_attrbute

contact_attibute_type

where the databse “contact_attibute_type” is meant for “company” and “phone”. The second table i.e.  “contact_attrbute” is meant for the actual values  of “company” and “phone”.

Now I need a way to validate those values before I write them in hibernate, thus  I am getting the “public UUID phone” and then trying to apply those constrains to the actual value I got from the user i.e. “+00112233445566778899”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the complete code I have come up with to validate your test-case (including a simple executable demo):

Annotations:

```
package annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target( {ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotNull
{

}

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target( {ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Size
{
    int min() default 0;
    int max();
}
```

The Predefined class:

```
public class Predefined
{
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 25)
    public UUID phone;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    public UUID company;

    public Predefined(UUID phone, UUID company)
    {
        this.phone = phone;
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

The validator class which iterates through the declared fields and checks their annotation and field/value mappings:

```
public class PredefinedValidator
{
    public boolean validate(Predefined predefined, Map<UUID, String> mappings)
    {
        if (predefined == null)
            return false;

        for (Field field :predefined.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        {
            if (field.getType().equals(UUID.class))
            {
                try
                {
                    Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
                    UUID uuid = (UUID)field.get(predefined);
                    if (!this.validateField(uuid, annotations, mappings))
                        return false;
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(PredefinedValidator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateField(UUID field, Annotation[] annotations, Map<UUID, String> mapping)
    {
        boolean containsSize = false;
        boolean containsNotNull = false;
        int minSize = -1;
        int maxSize = -1;

        // fetch which annotations are available for the provided field
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations)
        {
            if (annotation instanceof Size)
            {
                containsSize = true;
                Size size = (Size)annotation;
                minSize = size.min();
                maxSize = size.max();
            }
            else if (annotation instanceof NotNull)
                containsNotNull = true;
        }

        // check if the provided value is null and an annotatition for @NotNull
        // is set
        if (field == null && containsNotNull)
            return false;

        if (containsSize)
        {
            // get the value of the mapped UUID which we are going to validate
            String value = mapping.get(field);
            if (value == null && containsNotNull)
                return false;
            else if (value == null)
                return true;

            // check if the length of the value matches
            if (value.length() <= minSize || value.length() >= maxSize)
                return false;
        }

        // passed all tests
        return true;
    }
}
```

Last but not least a simple demo:

```
public static void main(String ... args)
{
    Map<UUID, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
    mappings.put(UUID.fromString("47b58767-c0ad-43fe-8e87-c7dae489a4f0"), "+00112233445566778899");
    mappings.put(UUID.fromString("f9a1e8f4-b8c0-41f2-a626-49c11da8d5c2"), "someVirtualCompnayName");       

    Predefined predefined = new Predefined(
            UUID.fromString("47b58767-c0ad-43fe-8e87-c7dae489a4f0"), 
            UUID.fromString("f9a1e8f4-b8c0-41f2-a626-49c11da8d5c2"));
    Predefined predefined2 = new Predefined(
            UUID.randomUUID(), 
            UUID.fromString("f9a1e8f4-b8c0-41f2-a626-49c11da8d5c2"));
    Predefined predefined3 = new Predefined(
            null, 
            UUID.fromString("f9a1e8f4-b8c0-41f2-a626-49c11da8d5c2"));
    PredefinedValidator validator = new PredefinedValidator();

    System.out.println("predefined is valid: "+validator.validate(predefined, mappings));
    System.out.println("predefined is valid: "+validator.validate(predefined2, mappings));
    System.out.println("predefined is valid: "+validator.validate(predefined3, mappings));

    mappings.put(UUID.fromString("f9a1e8f4-b8c0-41f2-a626-49c11da8d5c2"), "someVirtualCompnayNamesomeVirtualCompnayNamesomeVirtualCompnayNamesomeVirtualCompnayName"); 
    System.out.println("predefined is valid: "+validator.validate(predefined, mappings));
}
```

HTH

Comment: Hello Roman, Sincerer "danke schön" and "мерси" for this replay. The answer was beyond, what i was hopping to get. Again thank you.

Comment: @Tito no need to thank. SO maintains a voting based system, if the answer solved your question accept the answer as solution. If you agree to the content of a post, up-vote the answer; if you disagree, comment on the post and discuss your statements and optionally down-vote if you think that the answer does not solve the problem at all or lacks any proper hint on how to deal with the origin problem